# How center of group is subset of centralizer of an element $a$ of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the book "contemporary abstract algebra by gallian" author writes:

> Notice that for every element $a$ of a group $G$, $Z(G) \subseteq C(a)$.

I proved above statement like this:
**Proof**: Suppose $a \in Z(G)$ then $ax=xa$ for every $x \in G$. By definition of centralizer of $a$ in $G$ we deduce that $a \in C(a)$.

I felt the problem when I used the proof steps on an example. I supposed the group $$Q_8:= \{\pm 1,\pm i \pm j,\pm k\}$$
Under multiplication. Then $Z(Q_8)=\{ \pm 1\}$ and $C(i)=\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$. Here i stuck because in the proof above I started by letting $a \in Z(G)$, but here in the example $i \notin Z(Q_8)$. Where is the mistake? Is my proof incorrect or am I making some mistake in example?

**Note**: $Z(G):=\{g \in G:xg=gx$ for all $x \in G \}$ and $C(a):=\{x \in G:ax=xa\}$.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, your little proposition says that the centralizer of any element contains the center of the group, and that's exactly what you showed in your example, since $$Z(Q_8)=\{ ±1\}\subset C(i)=\{±1,±i\}$$

Comment: @Fotis Actually my question is: If $a ∈ C(a)$, then it is not necessary $a$ is in $Z(G)$. So if i want to prove proposition for the case when $a ∉ Z(G)$, then how will the step goes?

Comment: That's just by the two definitions: if an element commutes with *every* element of the group (nemely if it lays in the center), then it commutes in particular with any specific $a$ (namely it lays in the centralizer of such $a$).

Comment: Oh, now I understand your problem, I posted an answer on where your mistake was on the proof, followed by a correct proof

Comment: @citadel Oh I understood you point. But suppose $a$ is an element (lays in centralizer but not center) s.t $a$ does commute with all elements of group. So $a ∉ Z(G)$ right, so my proof is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your proof, you wrongly assumed that $a\in Z(G)$, as this is not the general case (e.g. the example you gave).

A correct proof would be:

Let $a\in G$ and consider $C(a)$.
Now, for any $g\in Z(G)$, we have that $gx=xg$ for every $x\in G$, by the definition of $Z(G)$.

In particular, for $x=a$, we have $ga=ag$.
Now by the definition of $C(a)$, we conclude that $g\in C(a)$, and since $g$ was an arbitrary element of $Z(G)$, we get: $Z(G)⊆ C(a)$

With the above proof, we never make the wrong assumption that the arbitrary element $a\in G$ is a central element of the group.

Comment: I understood. I misunderstood whole stuff just because of my incorrect proof.